# Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'opencv2\opencv.hpp' in VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I am trying to run the simple test code below on Visual Studio 2015 with OpenCv 3.1 on windows 10.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
namedWindow("win");
waitKey(0);
return 1;
}
```

But i get

> Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'opencv2\opencv.hpp': No such
>   file or directory

I have added the Path `C: \ opencv \ build \ x64 \ vc14 \ bin` to System variable in the Windows Environment variables.

Also in Visual studio I have set the Include Directories `C:\opencv\build\include;$(IncludePath)` under `Project properties > VC++ Directories` and also the `Linker > Input Additional Dependencies` set to `opencv_world310d.lib` (Debug)

I also have the following setting:

Executable Directories - `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14`

Library Directories - `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`

Additional Library Directories - `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Does `C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2` contain the `opencv.hpp` file?

Comment: Yes it does C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp

Comment: OpenCV is a pain to get working with Visual Studio on a per-project basis! It's slower, but I usually just use Accord and pull it in with nuget!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution finally, on the Project > Properties I had to change platform to x64 and the set the bin, lib and include folders again